# Calling function bad argument

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a game and I got a problem with function showing player:

```
function Furry() {
  this.board=document.querySelectorAll('#board div');
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.direction = "right";
}
```

and:

```
showFurry=function(){
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  this.board[ this.position(this.furry.x , this.furry.y) ].classList.add('furry');
}
```

and in consol when I want to call function I got this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

https://jsfiddle.net/mdx3w24c/

At this state after calling function showFurry and showCoin I should receive this:
[image]

Comment: with this small info nobody can help you here cause nobody knows where/when/why showFurry is called, is it part of something bigger, what is the context/this... etc. pls provide the complete code, a jsbin/fiddle would also help a lot ;)

Comment: do you mean `this.x` instead of `this.furry.x`? same for `y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the functions `showFurry` and `showCoin`. Then, make a function in the Game class that will do those things.

```
Game.prototype.start = function() {
    this.board[this.position(this.coin.x, this.coin.y)].classList.add('coin');
    this.board[this.position(this.furry.x, this.furry.y)].classList.add('furry');
};
```

Then when you start your game, instead of calling `showFurry` and `showCoin` you can call `Game.start()`;

```
var game = new Game();
game.start();
```

Also your Coin constructor set random values to x & y, but the furry construct set them both to 0, then set them to random values in the `showFurry` function. In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx3w24c/1/) fiddle, I've moved that to the constructor.